# Add repeating values as new column in R

Tags: r, variables, repeat, rep

I would like to add a new column to my data set that contains the numbers 1 - 46 and repeats them 12 times. That is 12 times 1, 12 times 2, 12 times 3 etc.
Can anyone help me how to do this?

Thank you!

I tried

```
new <- rep(c(1:46, each,  times = 12))
```

but it gives the numbers 1 - 46 ongoing..

Comment: `rep(1:46, each = 12)`

Answer (score 0):

Note that R will use vectors multiple times as long as the vector length is an integer multiple of the reference vector, e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:92, b = 1:46)
```

generates a dataframe with column a = 1:92 and column b = 1:46 twice.  The reference vector is `1:nrow(df)`.  In your case 1:46 declared once would be replicated 11 times